# Overpopulation and the Tree of Life

Tags: parashat-bereishit, science, demography

Had it not been for the sin of Adam and Chava, I've read sources that say we would have been able to eat from the Tree of Life, which would means that humanity would never die. What would keep the Earth from being over-populated?

Comment: If you're assuming a different nature, as in perpetual life, then perhaps the earth itself would also have a different nature, and would keep expanding, in order to be able to accommodate the constant increase in population.

Comment: https://www.mishnahyomit.com/articles/Avot/The%20Miracle%20of%20Bowing

Comment: I remember Rav Saadya Gaon addressing a similar question regarding the World to Come in Emunos v'Deos.

Answer (score -1):

Adam and Eve did not bear any children before they ate of the fruit.

Comment: Except that rashi and gemara sanhedrin say they did.

Comment: Where is that said?

Comment: @Shlomy https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%94_%D7%90 I think you are right. אמר ר"ל בואו ונחזיק טובה לאבותינו שאלמלא הן לא חטאו אנו לא באנו לעולם ... למימרא דאי לא חטאו לא הוו מולדו... והאמר ר"ל מאי דכתיב (בראשית ה, א) זה ספר תולדות אדם וגו' וכי ספר היה לו לאדם הראשון מלמד שהראה לו הקב"ה לאדם הראשון דור דור ודורשיו דור דור וחכמיו דור דור ופרנסיו ... וא"ר יוסי אין בן דוד בא עד שיכלו נשמות שבגוף שנאמר (ישעיהו נז, טז) [כי לא לעולם אריב ולא לנצח אקצוף] כי רוח מלפני יעטוף ונשמות אני עשיתי לא תימא אנו לא באנו לעולם אלא כמי שלא באנו לעולם